# Undefined Input Shape in Keras Model with Data Augmentation and MobileNet Base

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i'm trying to make a data augmentation to this model and it shows an error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. 
Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)
```

the error happens in Flatten layer when i remove it and change it like AvaragePoolin2D the error vanish but error show in the fit method says Graph execution error: Detected at node 'Equal' defined at (most recent call last):

when i move the data augm line x = data_aug(inputs) there was no error

```py
data_aug = keras.Sequential([
    layers.RandomWidth(0.2),
    layers.RandomHeight(0.2),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
    layers.RandomFlip("horizontal")
])
keras.backend.clear_session()
base_mobilenet = keras.applications.MobileNet(
    weights = 'imagenet',
    include_top = False, 
    input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
)
base_mobilenet.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape = (224, 224, 3))
x = data_aug(inputs)
x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
x = base_mobilenet(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(category_count, activation = "softmax")(x)
mobilenet_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
mobilenet_aug_model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
                        loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                        metrics = ["accuracy"]
)
callbacks=[
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience = 5, restore_best_weights = True),  
    keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', factor = 0.7, patience = 2, verbose = 1),
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint( filepath = "mobilenet_augmented_model.keras",save_best_only = True,monitor = "val_loss")
]
history = mobilenet_aug_model.fit( 
    train_dataset, 
    steps_per_epoch = Train_groups, 
    epochs = 20,
    validation_data = validation_dataset,
    validation_steps = Valid_groups,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```